# Why cant I get rid of RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to divide a numpy array by a shifted version of itself. The array contains `0` so naturally there will be a divide by zero issue. But I figured inserting a `np.where` would sort that out. It did not.

```
import numpy as np

tpx = np.array([0.95, 0.9, 0.85, 0.80, 0.75, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
px = np.where(tpx[:-1]!=0, tpx[1:]/tpx[:-1], 0)

px = np.where(tpx[:-1]!=0, tpx[1:]/tpx[:-1], 0)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
Out[4]: 
array([0.94736842, 0.94444444, 0.94117647, 0.9375    , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        ])
```

I also tried using `np.isclose` like so

```
px = np.where(np.isclose(tpx[:-1], 0, atol=1e-12)==False, tpx[1:]/tpx[:-1], 0)
```

But it still issues a warning. How can I get rid of this warning? The result, however, looks ok.

I dont really want to start slicing the array, because it is important that the resulting array retains its size.

Comment: replace zeros with NaNs

Comment: Looks like it works. If you want "credit" for your response. Post it as an answer an I'll tag it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works if you replace zeros with NaNs